# Possible to Code a TTF/OTF/SVG font?

Tags: fonts, font-face, truetype

I wonder if it is possible to "code" a TTF/OTF/SVG font? Somehow write in all the cordinates for each letter.

**If so, where can I learn more about it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly possible.  [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/) and [SVG Fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html) are both XML documents.  So, assuming you have a way to lay out the letter forms in SVG-compatible shapes, the rest should be straightforward, assuming good XML support.

You can then use FontForge to [convert](http://voices.yahoo.com/use-fontforge-convert-fonts-otf-ttf-pfb-pfm-6391402.html?cat=15) to other formats.

*Edit*:  Another question produced [a manual way to produce SVG Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635313/3438854), which should be useful in guiding the design of a program to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Create fonts, glyphs and contours using the Fontforge Python extension (This doesn't open the GUI). All popular formats and UFO. http://fontforge.org/python.html

RoboFab is a Python library with objects that deal with data usually associated with fonts and type design. RoboFab has support for the UFO font format. http://www.robofab.org/

UFO is a Unified Font Format (XML). http://unifiedfontobject.org/